# Html.BeginForm css properties without action and controller

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have 2 actions in my controller, Create and Edit, that essentially uses the same view, as the function of adding and editing a record is the same.

So in my view, I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

I could just use `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { }`

But that way, I don't see any overload method to add in my css class files

How do I use the same BeginForm helper for both my Create and Edit actions without having to hard code it?

Or what other ways, or best practices should be employed if I want to set a style to my form tag, which will be used for 2 different actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the same thing as you, with one view for both actions. In the controller, I just pass a ViewBag property, called Action which is set dependeding on the context. In the view, just call @Html.BeginForm(ViewBag.Action, ...).

Comment: also you can check if Model is null, ex: BeginForm(Model == null ? "Create" : "Edit", ...)

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is create a css file and include it in the view layout.

```
<link href="**.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

inside css:

```
form {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as this seems like a good idea to reuse the same view for both I can tell you that eventually you will have to split them up, usually as a result of some new feature requested that applies to only one or the other. It's a good idea to get into the practice of having a dedicated view for both Edit and Create. A good compromise between this and keeping them DRY is to have the views contain the begin form tags, maybe some JavaScript if needed or any other references, but for the fields themselves use @Html.EditorFor() and create an EditorTemplate for that datatype. That way it still keeps the DRY principle as much as possible but still letting you stick to the single responsibility principle. Granted if they do get even more complex it's possible that the shared EditorTemplate may need to change as well, in which case you may need to split this as well in the future and use something like `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x, "CustomerEdit")`

Generally it's a bad practice to let the the concerns of the view (generating the form URL) be dictated by the controller.

Views/Customers/Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x)
}
```

Views/Customers/Edit.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Customers", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x)
}
```

Views/Customers/EditorTemplates/Customer.cshtml

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="text">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="text">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
...etc
```